# Is there a function to know how many times a column has the best value?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame like this :

```
A    B    C

4    8    2

1    3    5

5    7    6
```

It could have more column and lines.

So what I'd like to know is for each column how many times they have the lowest values (in my example the result should be 2 for A and 1 for C).

Comment: By "best value", do you mean "lowest value in the row"?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = data.frame(a = c(4, 1, 5), b = c(8, 3, 7), c = c(2, 5, 6))

row_mins = apply(d, 1, min)
# alternately, slightly more efficient
row_mins = do.call(pmin, d)

colSums(d == row_mins)
# a b c 
# 2 0 1
```

Comment: I would advise `do.call(pmin,df1)` instead of `apply`, so you don't do implicit matrix conversion

Comment: Thank you very much ! And is there some function to order them so I can have a classement of which one is better than the other or should I do it by myself ?

Comment: See `?sort` or `?order`.

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if you could tell me if it should work when NA are present in the data frame, because I just had a case where I have NA in my data frame (I don't want to delete them) and the colSums isn't working anymore.

Comment: `pmin`, `colSums`, and `min` take `na.rm` arguments to ignore NA values. `do.call` is annoying with extra args, but `apply` works fine, something like `row_mins = apply(d, 1, min, na.rm = TRUE)` and then `colSums(d == row_mins, na.rm = TRUE)` should work.